# Overloading casting Operator: C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to cast two classes `Pounds` and `Cents`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Pounds;
//Overloading Casting Operators: Pounds and Cents
class Cents{
    int mCents;
    public:
    Cents(int n);
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,const Cents& c);
    operator Pounds();
    };

class Pounds{
    int mPounds;
    public:
    Pounds(int n);
    operator Cents();
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,const Pounds& p);
    };

Cents::Cents(int n):mCents(n){}

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,const Cents& c){
    os << c.mCents;
    return os;
    }

Cents::operator Pounds(){
    double d=mCents/100.0 ;
    cout << d << endl;
    return d;
    }

Pounds::Pounds(int n):mPounds(n){}

Pounds::operator Cents(){
    return mPounds*100;
    }

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os,const Pounds& p){
    os << p.mPounds;
    return os;
    }



int main()
{

    Pounds Pnd(4);
    cout << (Cents) Pnd << endl;

    Cents Cnt(456);
    cout.precision(3);
    cout << showpoint << (Pounds) Cnt << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

My question is very simple. Why the output is showing as:

```
$ ./Trial
400
4.56
4
```

I mean inside the cast operator `Pounds()` it is showing real decimal valie `4.56` but inside main `4`. Not able to figure out, what is happening.

Comment: `int mPounds` and `Pounds(int n)` might give you a clue.

Comment: In other words, change `int` to `double` or `float`

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Add yours as an answer. It's the right one, and I want to vote you up!

Comment: storing Pounds as a double or float will possibly lose accuracy, that means - lose money:)

Comment: Check [Fowler's Money Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) to get a production ready solution.

Comment: @MikeSeymour No I want something of sort int/float and to get result in decimal, inside the cast operator it displays correctly but while returning, does not show the decimal result

Comment: @GauravK: Returning the `float` converts it to `Pound`, using the constructor that takes an `int`. You'll need to use something other than `int` if you want to represent fractions. (`float` is probably good enough, if your code isn't intended to work with real money.)

Comment: @MikeSeymour I tried to define another constructor such as `Pounds(double d){}` .. is there any way so that it can promote its `int` member `mPounds` to `double`. I mean to say if I can not redefine the class `Pounds` member `mPounds` to `double`, is there any method which can give me decimal conversion to `double` with `Pounds` casting of `Cents`?